# C referencing C++ extern

Tags: c++, c, windows, extern, icc

I have a header file in a Windows compile using the Intel compiler.  The header looks something like this:

```
#ifdef _MAIN
    Loggerp        logger;
#else
    extern Loggerp logger;
#endif
```

The _MAIN macro is defined in a C++ file and there is a C file that includes the header.  This generates a "...LNK2019: unresolved external symbol..." because the C++ compile decorates (mangles) the 'logger' name such that the linker can't match the undecorated C name with the decorated C++ name.

The MSVC docs state that the MS compiler will support both 'extern "C"' and 'extern "C++"'.  However, the Intel compiler marks the quote mark of 'extern "' as an error.

Anyone know how to get the Intel compiler to mark this reference so that it can be linked to both C++ and C ?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_MAIN`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Comment: Thanks, that was my fault, the #define was different and I just deleted the first part of it which ended up leaving the _ prefix.  Still good observation.

Comment: You can probably abstract away the manufacturers. Are you building the C part with ICC and the C++ part with MSVS? (note that both can do either) Clarify for extra upvotes!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Both parts are built using ICC.  Most of the references to logger were from C++ files, only one was from a C file.  I mentioned MSVC because I thought the MSVC 'extern "C++"' might be a good approach, but it didn't seem ICC supported it.

Comment: It sounds like you think `extern "C++"` is a MSVC thing. It isn't. It's a part of C++. You might want to remove the references to Visual Studio from your question, if you are not using it. FWIW I see no evidence elsewhere that ICC is non-compliant in this regard. A [mcve] would be a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cpp
// when compiling C++ code, use the non-mangled C names
#ifdef __cplusplus
# define EXTERN extern "C"
#else
# define EXTERN extern 
#endif

EXTERN Loggerp logger;
```

Comment: One of my favorite nits: use the C-mangled names. C compilers also mangle names, typically by prepending an underscore. One compiler that I used many years ago appended an underscore.

Comment: That put me on the right track.  There was a chicken and egg problem, such that when _MAIN was defined __cplusplus was also defined.  Moving that section out of the #if _MAIN and using the code you described allowed the compile to proceed.